# C# MVC3 - "The resource cannot be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create another controller for my Ajax handler - so now I have an AppController (The site controller) and an AjaxController (the Ajax request handler).

The problem is, that when I access http://LocalHost:82/Ajax , I get `The resource cannot be found`. When I access http://LocalHost:82/Ajax/Index , it works.

The problem is the default routing, right? Here is my routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "App", action = "NewRequests", id = UrlParameter.Optional     } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

If you need more info dont hesitate to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "App", action = "NewRequests", id = UrlParameter.Optional     } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Declares that default action is NewRequests, so it is expected that your AjaxController would have [HttpGet] NewRequests actions. You can do that by,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewRequests()
{
  // ...
}
```

or

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("NewRequests")]
public ActionResult WhatEverNameOfActionYouLike()
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Aaah! I see! I was comparing this project with one that worked, and now I notice how the routing works! Thanks!

Comment: - one thing though, whats the [HttpGet] good for? I have never used it in my own action methods?

Comment: these are Action attributes, that you can control which HTTP verb this action could handle. There are: HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete

Comment: Ok, thanks! The way I see it they are not necesarry for my particular case. :)

Answer (score 2):

Is there an NewRequests method returning an ActionResult in the Ajax controller? If not, this makes sense as your default action is NewRequests.

Comment: I just realized that! My bad. :)